# Compute the probability that at least one of the angles of the triangle  exceeds $x\pi$.

Tags: probability, random-variables

**Let $A,B,C$ be three points, chosen independently and uniformly at random on the circumference of a circle. Let $b(x)$ be the probability that at least one of the angles of the triangle $ABC$ exceeds $x\pi$. Show that**

$$
b(x)= 1-(3x-1)^2\ \ \ \ \  \mbox{if}\ \ \frac{1}{3}\leq x\leq \frac{1}{2};\\   
b(x)= 3(1-x)^2  \ \ \ \ \  \mbox{if}\  \frac{1}{2}\leq x\leq 1.
$$

This is duplicate of [Compute the probability that at least one of the angles of the triangle $ABC$ exceeds $x\pi$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2237562/compute-the-probability-that-at-least-one-of-the-angles-of-the-triangle-abc-ex) . But the answer to other question does not solve using Integration.

The following is the working I am doing.

My computation is as follows: Without loss of generality, we assume the circle is unit circle.
Let $A=(1,0),\ B=(1,\theta), $ and $C=(1,\phi)$ where $0<\theta<\phi<2\pi$. It is obvious that the joint density function $f(\theta,\phi)=(2\pi^2)^{-1}$ with $0<\theta<\phi<2\pi.$ Moreover, we have
$$
\angle A=\frac{1}{2}(\phi-\theta),\ \ \angle B=\pi-\frac{\phi}{2},\ \ \mbox{and}\ \ 
\angle C=\frac{1}{2}\theta.
$$
First, consider $x\in [1/3,1/2]$. I tried to compute the probability that all angles are less than $x\pi$ as follows:
$$
\frac{1}{2}\theta \leq x\pi,\ \ \frac{1}{2}(\phi-\theta)\leq x\pi,\ \ \mbox{and} \ \ \pi-\frac{1}{2}\phi\leq x\pi.
$$
Thus, we have
$$
\theta \in [0,2x\pi],\ \ \mbox{and}\ \ \phi\in [2(1-x)\pi,2x\pi+\theta]. 
$$
Hence,
$$
\int_{0}^{2x\pi}\int_{2(1-x)\pi}^{2x\pi+\theta}\frac{1}{2\pi^2}d\phi d\theta =\frac{1}{2\pi^2}\int_{0}^{2x\pi} [2x\pi+\theta-2\pi+2x\pi]d\theta = \\
\frac{1}{2\pi^2}\int_{0}^{2x\pi} [2\pi(2x-1)+\theta]d\theta = \frac{1}{2\pi^2}[(2\pi)(2x-1)(2x\pi)+2x^2\pi^2] =5x^2-2x. 
$$
Thus, I obtain $b(x)=1-(5x^2-2x)=-5x^2+2x+1.$

I am not sure what mistake I am doing here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compute the probability that at least one of the angles of the triangle $ABC$ exceeds $x\pi$](/q/2237562).  It is using integration --- the area of the region is what your integral gives.

Comment: I am looking forward for a rigorous proof, I am making the same mistake as in the question and looking to fix the integration.

Comment: Are you asking for someone to point out the mistake in the integration steps at that link? Or did you have slightly different steps that also don't seem to be working? (You could share them and we could spot your error.) Are you having trouble setting up integration to match the pictures in the answer to that linked question? (If you haven't yet tried, it's a good exercise.)

Comment: @MarkS. I have updated the question with my current working steps. Looking for where I am making mistake .

Comment: You updated it with the working steps from the other question, not your own work. The error with the steps at the other question was pointed out in the answer to the other question ("your integral over $θ$ is starting at $θ=0$, but the red region doesn't actually reach $θ=0$"). But since I didn't initially realize you had copied the work verbatim, I feel I wasted some of my time redoing the work done in the answer to the other question.

Comment: Being charitable, it seems like you might want to ask "Can someone explain that problem with the inequalities in an algebraic way rather than appealing to a diagram?", but I'm just guessing. Please take time to review the answer to the other question, be clear about what is and is not your work, and try to clarify what exactly you are asking that is not answered by the answer to the other question.